# Invalid MultiPolygon value even though all the Polygons are valid

Tags: python, geojson, geopandas, shapely

I am trying to convert coordinates to WKT format. Here I have a list of polygons which should be identified as a Multi polygon.

```
 'geometry': [[[129093.87770000007, 6638201.563100001],
   [129145.82270000037, 6638246.0934],
   [129170.66339999996, 6638267.387800001],
   [129234.25879999995, 6638194.9081],
   [129263.13030000031, 6638162.0021],
   [129256.51460000034, 6638153.420600001],
   [129264.29519999959, 6638144.4186],
   [129227.29739999957, 6638111.6921],
   [129198.93099999987, 6638086.598099999],
   [129197.43379999977, 6638085.2764],
   [129189.4422000004, 6638094.0996],
   [129176.43039999995, 6638108.3499],
   [129159.07469999976, 6638127.3638],
   [129151.15539999958, 6638136.5965],
   [129133.93259999994, 6638156.149599999],
   [129159.67819999997, 6638179.257999999],
   [129154.22589999996, 6638185.2235],
   [129151.20010000002, 6638188.5338],
   [129146.49629999977, 6638193.680299999],
   [129143.46549999993, 6638196.9956],
   [129136.80140000023, 6638191.0813],
   [129117.92229999974, 6638174.326099999],
   [129101.88219999988, 6638192.5428],
   [129100.7592000002, 6638193.8189],
   [129093.87770000007, 6638201.563100001]],
  [[128941.56969999988, 6638372.659700001],
   [128943.42590000015, 6638374.3345],
   [128960.41220000014, 6638389.665999999],
   [128973.69660000037, 6638401.5129],
   [128996.57529999968, 6638375.679],
   [128987.46860000025, 6638367.0911],
   [128983.83999999985, 6638363.6691],
   [128972.29009999987, 6638376.4816],
   [128953.31819999963, 6638359.575999999],
   [128943.23959999997, 6638370.7996],
   [128941.56969999988, 6638372.659700001]],
  [[129090.9358000001, 6638503.8179],
   [129097.49689999968, 6638510.4618],
   [129097.59499999974, 6638513.236199999],
   [129134.7444000002, 6638546.606799999],
   [129147.49670000002, 6638558.0616],
   [129149.08770000003, 6638558.060900001],
   [129150.47169999965, 6638558.0603],
   [129176.9729000004, 6638534.216700001],
   [129176.96339999977, 6638531.551899999],
   [129160.03479999956, 6638516.535],
   [129124.70949999988, 6638485.1993],
   [129121.82320000045, 6638485.3100000005],
   [129115.54370000027, 6638479.5166],
   [129090.9358000001, 6638503.8179]],
  [[129158.46559999976, 6638281.2897],
   [129181.3964999998, 6638301.693600001],
   [129202.42819999997, 6638320.4079],
   [129222.96760000009, 6638338.684900001],
   [129228.84059999976, 6638332.3202],
   [129164.44720000029, 6638274.4724],
   [129158.46559999976, 6638281.2897]],
  [[129129.06099999975, 6638386.475199999],
   [129155.41009999998, 6638410.2303],
   [129169.55939999968, 6638422.9824],
   [129172.49909999967, 6638422.9364],
   [129180.67559999973, 6638429.6515],
   [129180.72410000023, 6638433.040999999],
   [129214.33800000045, 6638463.1961],
   [129235.7324000001, 6638482.398399999],
   [129238.75250000041, 6638482.4419],
   [129272.70870000031, 6638453.891899999],
   [129276.91830000002, 6638450.3521],
   [129311.60599999968, 6638421.1872000005],
   [129313.13900000043, 6638419.8989],
   [129312.24859999958, 6638419.095799999],
   [129319.1475999998, 6638413.4484],
   [129256.64639999997, 6638357.3002],
   [129250.38129999954, 6638363.2841],
   [129248.93879999965, 6638364.661900001],
   [129224.56620000023, 6638387.8639],
   [129203.5848000003, 6638407.837400001],
   [129202.72339999955, 6638408.6601],
   [129195.30989999976, 6638401.2228999995],
   [129179.70480000041, 6638385.5688000005],
   [129178.5390999997, 6638384.5253],
   [129160.28000000026, 6638368.1357],
   [129151.56759999972, 6638360.3236],
   [129129.06099999975, 6638386.475199999]]],
 'type': 'MultiPolygon'}
```

The following code will resulting an error

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon, MultiPolygon
MultiPolygon(jk['geometry'])
```

Resulting Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/shapely/geometry/multipolygon.py:189, in geos_multipolygon_from_polygons(arg)
    188 try:
--> 189     N = len(exemplar[0][0])
    190 except TypeError:

TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [68], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 MultiPolygon(jk['geometry'])

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/shapely/geometry/multipolygon.py:60, in MultiPolygon.__init__(self, polygons, context_type)
     58     return
     59 elif context_type == 'polygons':
---> 60     geom, n = geos_multipolygon_from_polygons(polygons)
     61 elif context_type == 'geojson':
     62     geom, n = geos_multipolygon_from_py(polygons)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/shapely/geometry/multipolygon.py:191, in geos_multipolygon_from_polygons(arg)
    189     N = len(exemplar[0][0])
    190 except TypeError:
--> 191     N = exemplar._ndim
    193 assert N == 2 or N == 3
    195 subs = (c_void_p * L)()

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_ndim'
```

But the inner polygons seems to be fine and this code works perfectly.

```
import shapely
for item in jk['geometry']:
    print(shapely.wkt.dumps(Polygon(item)))
```

Why this is happening? Why Iam not able to convert to Multypolygon directly to WKT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MultiPolygon takes a sequence of rings ***and*** holes list tuples, or a sequence of polygons. You can either do:

```
MultiPolygon((x, None) for x in jk['geometry'])
```

or

```
MultiPolygon(Polygon(x) for x in jk['geometry'])
```